# Store ms word data to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, ms-word

I wrote a rich-text area in which I can copy the data from MS word. After copying to rich-text area. I am storing this data to MySQL database using PHP. Now it sometime happens that while copying from MS word it is having a lot of tags due to which data stored in MySQL gets trimmed.
Please help me if you have done something similar before. 
I only want to facilitate a rich text area which allow user to copy and paste through MS Word and can store that data to MySQL successfully.

Comment: Check if the column data type size is big enough to store data read from textarea field. Modify it suitably.

Comment: Otherwise, please add your code to the question, so we can look at what you are doing and try to figure it out.

Comment: What is your table schema? Are you using `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1):

Rich Text box can contain all html tags and value so when ever you are coping the data from Word file its also coping extra tags. if you don't want to store that data to your mysql database then plese use plain Textbox which will help you to filter copied text.

or you should change the data type of column to 'TEXT' this datatype can store all text and html data